# Refunded Emission Payments - how does it work?

Tags: payment-system

I know that there are different types of **Refunded emission payments** e.g., :

- expenditure based
- output based

However, I think it is difficult to understand how **Refunded emission payments** works?
I would be great full for a simple explanation on how it works and/or resources that explains this concept in an easy way.